# Verificar si una tabla posee registros en MySQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta función en php para saber si una tabla existe, que funciona perfectamente:

```
    function mysql_table_existe($tableName)
{
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '.$tableName;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = @mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Pero estoy migrando a php 7.2 y me esta dando algunos problemas. Estoy conectando mediante:

```
$db_link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $nombre_base);
```

y hasta ahora no tengo problemas, mas que con esta funcion
intenté sin exito:

```
    function mysql_table_existe($tableName)
{
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '.$tableName;
    $result = mysqli_query($db_link, $query);
    $num_rows = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num_rows)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: considera quitale el arroba a la función mysqli y compartenos de ser posible el error que te esta presentando

Comment: Se lo quité, siempre dice que no existe, incluso si agrego echo $num_rows; antes del if, la variable esta vacía

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ojo que me parece lo que buscas con tu código no es saber si la tabla existe sino contar si tiene registros o no que es lago distinto, ya que pudiéramos tener una tabla sin registros pero que si existe.

Considera hacer los siguientes cambios:

- Usa una función anónima a la cual le pasaremos el nombre de la tabla que esta en una variable en forma de argumento
- Después para acceder a la variable que almacena la conexión haremos uso de `use` para llevar al contexto de la función anónima dicha variable
- De preferencia no arrobes las funciones pues me parece que hacerlo implica silenciar los errores que se pudieran estar generando

Tu consulta pudiera quedar así:

```
<?php 

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");

$tableName;

$hasData = function ($tableName) use($conexion) 
{
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$tableName);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta)) 
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

echo $hasData("tableName");
```

> Solo adaptalo a tu ejercicio

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicación

Answer (score 2):

como dice aprendiz, tu consulta esta refiriendo a que la tabla tenga registros, no que exista como tal. Eso seria revisando el schema de la bbdd.

Yo consideraria utilizar la siguiente SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '[table name]';
```

ya que estarias revisando, en la información de schemas de mysql, sobre una base de datos, la informacion de la tabla. En este caso, con el count obtendrias una linea si hay una tabla en esa bbdd, o 0 si no existe dicho registro.

o en caso de algo un poco mas "estandar":

```
show tables like '[table name]';
```

lo de estandar lo dejo entre comillas, porque no puedo probarlo directamente (si estas utilizando mysql te funciona, pero habria que verificar con otros motores de BBDD)